# akka-http has mixed java and scala dsl definitions, preventing compilation

Tags: scala, akka-http

There's the following error that happens when trying to compile the line of code in the error message. Removing `withStatus` makes the code compile.

> [error] /home/anton/code/flow-mobile/server/src/main/scala/in/flow/server/FlowServerStack.scala:108: type mismatch;
>
> [error]  found   : akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse
>
> [error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
>
> [error]         r mapEntity {_ transformDataBytes errorFlow(ermsg) } withStatus code

For some reason the function signature is this (even though it is found in the scala dsl package)

```
  override def withStatus(statusCode: Int): 
    akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse = copy(status = statusCode)
  override def withStatus(statusCode: akka.http.javadsl.model.StatusCode): 
    akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse = copy(status = statusCode.asInstanceOf[StatusCode])
```

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

The `withStatus` method is probably intended as a builder pattern helper to be used with Java.

If you want to alter a `HttpResponse` from Scala I reckon it would be more idiomatic to use `.copy(status = StatusCodes.OK)`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you are supposed to use the `copy` method to change statusCode, headers etc with Scala dsl's HttpResponse. Other `withXYZ` methods are more for the internal workings of Java api.

```
val originalResponse = ...

val newResponse = originalResponse.copy(status = StatusCodes.OK)

// or
val newResponse = originalResponse.copy(status = StatusCodes.NotFound)
```

You can look at defined StatusCodes here - http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/StatusCodes$.html